# Accessing on first element inside collection

Tags: c#

If I'm sending object named Property which have Photos collection when I'm need only first element from that Photos collection like this, does this approach load all elements from collection and than assoc. only first like I want, or is this approach the one I need, first load from collection.

```
public PropertyHPViewModel(Property x)
{
    Id = x.Id;
    Created = x.Created;
    Title = x.Title;
    Photo = x.Photos.First();
}
```

Generated Sql from profiler

```
SELECT photos0_.PropertyId    as PropertyId1_,
       photos0_.Id            as Id1_,
       photos0_.Id            as Id1_0_,
       photos0_.ImageData     as ImageData1_0_,
       photos0_.ImageMimeType as ImageMim3_1_0_,
       photos0_.PropertyId    as PropertyId1_0_
FROM   Photo photos0_
WHERE  photos0_.PropertyId = 129 /* @p0 */
```

**Updated**
Since I have 20 of this generated queries all differeted only in last line

`WHERE  photos0_.PropertyId = xxx /* @p0 */`

where the number is photo id object, I must add that I have SELECT N+1 ALERT on this queries according to nhibernate profiler.

Comment: I'm sure profiling would tell you the answer.

Comment: @scottm updated question, photos0 is I guess first element in the collection so review your answer and post it like an answer, I will gladdly accept it.

Comment: There should be a `TOP 1` statement in the SQL query if it translated `First()` correctly

Comment: @panjo: You may be misinterpreting your profiler query. The `PropertyId = 129` part is there presumably to restrict your results to photos associated with `x` (whose `Id` happens to be 129). In SQL, `First()` would usually translate to `TOP 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the expression tree is collapsed, NHibernate should generate SQL to only retrieve a single entity.

Answer (score 1):

If x.Photos is not IQueryable, the .First() call cannot take part in the SQL query sent by your ORM. I suspect this is the case.

The only solution is to construct a query manually from the ISession.

Comment: please share manual query inside session having above code in mind.